# Only one signal from a for loop

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I'm working on an indicator that prints line to reversal. Since the lines are output in a for loop, I only want to output one signal per drawn line.
So if a line is drawn, the condition for a candle should be true once. Then the signal should be deleted and only with the next drawn line a true should be output again only with a candle. Here is the query for drawing the lines.

```
    if showPP
        for i = 0 to pivH.size() -1
            label.new(pivH.get(i).b, pivH.get(i).p, style=label.style_label_right, size=size.tiny, color=color.yellow)
            l = line.new(pivH.get(i).b, pivH.get(i).p, pivH.get(i).b +5, pivH.get(i).p, color=color.yellow, extend=extend.none)

        for i = 0 to pivL.size() -1
            label.new(pivL.get(i).b, pivL.get(i).p, style=label.style_label_right, size=size.tiny, color=color.blue)
            l = line.new(pivL.get(i).b, pivL.get(i).p, pivL.get(i).b +5, pivL.get(i).p, color=color.blue, extend=extend.none)
```